# How to get read an input along with whitespace and sort the input to 2 arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, input

I am a new C learner. I really need to help with the following example:
[image]

Here are my codes for the get_polynom function, please let me know how can I accept the input along with the whitespaces and store them in 2 different arrays according to the ques says. Thanks in advance :)

******* Note: I am not allowed to use any default C functions other than printf() and scanf().***********

```
void get_polynom( int coeff[ ], int exp[ ] )
{ 
    init_polynom( coeff, exp); /* calling the initialization function*/
    int i=1;
    int terms = 0;
    int inputs=0;
    int arr[ASIZE];


    scanf("%d", &terms);

    for(; i<terms*2; i++){
        scanf("%d", &inputs);
        arr[i] = inputs;
     printf( "Your array has these values: ", arr[i] );
    }

    for(i=0; i< terms; i++){
            coeff[i] = arr[2*i];
            exp[i] = arr[2*i +1];
    }
```

Comment: Better to post text as text rather than a picture of text.

Comment: I'm of the same opinion as @chux - posting as text (rather than an image of a text) makes it easier for other people with a similar problem to find the question.

Comment: Another benefit: It is also easier for folks who answer to cut/paste parts of the post.

Comment: This code looks fine to me, except that you should initialize `i` to `0` in the first loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have missed to initialize the variable `i` in the for loop `for(; i<terms*2; i++){`
and you didnt specify the format specifier `%d` here `printf( "Your array has these values: ", arr[i] );`

here is the working code, i have also written the `print_poylynom` function :-)

```
`#include<stdio.h>
void print_polynom(int coeff[],int exp[],int terms)
{
    int i=0;
    printf("the polynomial is \n");
    for(i=0;i<terms;i++)
    {
        printf("%dX^%d",coeff[i],exp[i]);
        if(i<terms-1)
            printf("+");
    }
}
void init_polynom(int coeff[], int exp[])
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        coeff[i]=0;
        exp[i]=0;
    }
}

void get_polynom( int coeff[ ], int exp[ ] )
{
    init_polynom( coeff, exp); //calling the initialization function
    int i=1;
    int terms = 0;
    int inputs=0;
    int arr[100];


    scanf("%d", &terms);    
    for(i=0; i<terms*2; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &inputs);
        arr[i] = inputs;
        printf( "Your array has these values:%d\n", arr[i] );
    }

    for(i=0; i< terms; i++)
    {
        coeff[i] = arr[2*i];
        exp[i] = arr[2*i +1];
    }
    print_polynom(coeff,exp,terms);
}

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int coeff[100],exp[100];
    get_polynom(coeff,exp);
    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: Well, `i` was initialized, it was just initialized to 1 instead of 0.